# How to determine connection is failed while window is opened

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've an editor window opened. And, I've a requirement to check that if it fails to connect to database or, connection is broken when window is opened, the window should be closed.

```
var window = new EditorWindow(group);
window .KeyDown += (sender, args) =>{
            if (args.Key == Key.Escape)
                window .Close();
        };
DialogHelper.ShowDialog(window);
```

And, for the change of database connection I've:

```
public dbState dbState 
{ 
get { return dbState ; }
private set
    {
       dbState = value;
       FirePropertyChanged("dbState ");
    }
}
```

I'm new to WPF so any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `dbState` a property of your `EditorWindow` class?

Comment: no, it's a property of database connection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wiring things up directly, you would add code inside your `EditorWindow` class subscribing to the `dbState` property change event, and when that even fires, in your handler you would call `this.Close()` method to close the window. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx for more details.

A cleaner way to do it would be to use an MVVM library and take advantage of event aggregation. For example, this is how Caliburn.Micro does it: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator.